# How to format a dataframe in rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I tried to use rmarkdown in rstudio. 
The problem is that I have a dataframe one col of which is a long string.
When I use rmarkdown  as the following:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
x1 <- c(1,2)
x2 <- c("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")
x3 <- c("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
       "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyy, yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy")

df <- data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2,x3=x3)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
df
```
````

and I get the following output(I use html):

```
##   x1                  x2
## 1  1      aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
## 2  2 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
##                                                                  x3
## 1    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
## 2 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyy, yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

First, I don't like to print x3 as a seperate line; second, I prefer left alignment. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: I have found one tip that may be useful: if df is a datafame, print with right=FALSE can work; but if df is a data.table, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control the width of the element with `options(width=x)`, and left align by calling `print(df, right=FALSE)`. You can hide this cruft (though you may not want to) with, for example:

````
---
title: "Interesting data.frame"
author: "Me"
date: "15 April 2015"
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
options(width=100)
```


```{r}
x1 <- c(1,2)
x2 <- c("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")
x3 <- c("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyy, yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy")

df <- data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2,x3=x3)
```

```{r, eval=FALSE}
df
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
print(df, right=FALSE)
```
````

... which yields ...

---

[image]

Comment: @jbaums. how should I go about if I want the output that resembles the one from `View(mydata)` and not the output which is in your example? Thanks

Comment: @kRazzyR - If I understand you correctly, install the `DT` package and try `datatable(mydata)` (See https://rstudio.github.io/DT/ for some examples)

Comment: @jbaums thanks very much. It was exactly what I was looking for. It worked like a charm